# C# - WPF - update progressbar from another class

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

I'm here to ask for some help regarding C# and especially WPF. :D

I have a WPF project and I need to update the value of a progressbar from another class. The progressbar is in class 'NdWindow' and I need to update its value from class 'Automator'.

I already tried some things but nothing worked for me.

In 'NdWindow' class:

```
public partial class NdWindow : Window
{
    public NdWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public NdWindow(int progress)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        setprogress(progress);
    }

    public void setprogress(int progress)
    {
        this.progressBar.Value = progress;
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(progress));
    }
```

And in 'Automator' class:

```
public static void post()
{
    NdWindow test = new NdWindow();
    test.setprogress(10);
}
```

If I run the program, the MessageBox popups and shows me the value I have sent within setprogress().
I also tried sending the value within the constructor but it didn't help.

Please help me if you can. :D

Thanks!

PS: the 'post' function is executed by a button click. I have not written that code here. I hope this isn't a problem for you. :-)

Comment: check this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789926/update-a-progressbar-from-another-thread?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

In your `post` method you create new `NdWindow`, witch is not the window, where you want to change progressbar value.

You should somehow get `NdWindow` in `Automator` class.

```
public class Automator
{
   private NdWindow ndWindow;
   public Automator(NdWindow ndwindow)
   {
       this.ndWindow = ndwindow;
   }

   public void Post()
   {
       ndWindow.setprogress(10);
   }
}

public partial class NdWindow : Window
{
    private Automator automator;
    public NdWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.automator = new Automator(this);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Automator.Post();
    }
}
```

Or you could send NdWindow to your `post` method

```
public class Automator
{
   public static void Post(NdWindow ndWindow)
   {
       ndWindow.setprogress(10);
   }
}

public partial class NdWindow : Window
{
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Automator.Post(this);
    }
}
```