# refreshing progressbar while thread is runing in c# (wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, delegates, invoke

I have wpf application with button on it.

The click event of the button start process take for approximately 30-50 sec. 
I want to use progress bar while this thread is working.
out of this i try also dispatcher.invoke. no success.

this is my code:

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
      some code.....
      Engine.ProgressEvent += (percent) => Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => progressBarIndicator.Value = percent));
      some code...

    }
    private void btnFirmwareUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      some code...
      send data to hardware using functions in Engine class
      Engine e = new Engine();
      e.update();
    }
```

my Engine.cs :

```
Class Engine 
{
    public static event Action<double> ProgressEvent;

    public update()
    {

      ProgressEvent(10);
    }
}
```

the progress bar indeed get the update the progress bar in the correct value but the gui is not refreshing.
solutions any one?

Comment: Read this :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789926/wpf-c-sharp-update-progressbar-from-another-thread

Answer (score 2):

I suggest use a `BackgroundWorker` to update your `Main UI`.

Here is an example of how to implement a `progress bar` using a `BackgroundWorker`

[Progress bar](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-progressbar-control/)