# Update WPF ProgressBar from invoked action

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar, backgroundworker

First, I should mention that I have already read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5789926/5358284) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29872663/5358284) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22084969/5358284), but none of them seem to fix my problem.

Simply explained, I have an unmanaged DLL which is called several times inside an invoked action, i.e.

```
var d = new List<string>();
var myData = new StringBuilder();

this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    myDLL.GetDataFromIndex(2, myData);
    d.Add(myData.ToString());

    myDLL.GetDataFromIndex(3, myData);
    d.Add(myData.ToString());

    myDLL.GetDataFromIndex(4, myData);
    d.Add(myData.ToString());

    //....
}
    ), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
```

I want to show the progress of getting data by a `ProgressBar`. First, I tried to update the `ProgressBar` right after each DLL call by putting the following line after each `d.Add(...)`

```
pbStatus.Value = newValue;
```

It obviously didn't work and it also ruined `myDLL` calls. Then I learned that the `ProgressBar` must be updated through a `BackgroundWorker`, but I wasn't able to define a new `BackgroundWorker` inside the invoked action. Furthermore, the DLL calls take different times. For example, after `GetDataFromIndex(2, ...)` 20% of the process is completed, while the next indexes take 5 to 10 percent each. Now I have no idea how to update the `ProgressBar` right after each DLL call. Any hints or workarounds would be much appreciated due to my exhaustion from hours of pointless googling.

Comment: @MichalHainc I didn't paste the full code because without having the DLL it would have been useless. And I stated the problem as clear as possible. Ruining the dll calls mean that the dll got the right data before, but strangely, it didn't after. And there was no exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dispatcher actions are beeing executed in the UI thread. So your code design is bad at that point allready that you are doing some external call there. Move your PINVOKING to a background task / thread, and call dispatcher.invoke just to set the progressbar progress from the background thread.

As I promised, I created this github repository to demonstrate how to work with progressbar & background task ... it is WPF and I tried to follow the MVVM pattern.

https://github.com/michalhainc/ProgressBarMVVMDemo

Comment: I am on it. But.. are you sure about this?

Comment: Didn't fix my problem, but +1 anyway

Comment: Thank you Michal. That was very helpful